# How to find acronyms in a pdf file

Tags: python, regex, grep, acronym

In my thesis I need to add a list of acronyms. I wondered how it can be programmed. I've found the nice utility [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/), which also gets regular expressions. I used it in such a way:

```
pdfgrep "([A-Z]+)" thesis.pdf
```

This is the best regular expressions I've found for this purpose, though it gets also single capital letters. Does anyone has a better solution?
I wrote a Python code that deals with the output:

```
import subprocess 
import shlex
import re

FOLDER = 'full folder'
THESIS = '%s/thesis.pdf'%(FOLDER)
OUTPUT_FILE = '%s/acronymsInMyThesis.txt'%(FOLDER)
PATTERN = '([A-Z]+)'

def searchAcronymsInPDF():
    output = pdfSearch()
    acrs = []
    for reg in re.findall(PATTERN, output):
        reg.strip()
        if (len(reg)>1):
            acrs.append(reg)
    return set(acrs)

def pdfSearch():
    command = 'pdfgrep "%s" %s'%(PATTERN,THESIS)
    output = shellCall(command)
    return output

def shellCall(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, _ = p.communicate()
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    acrs = searchAcronymsInPDF()
    print(acrs)
```

Comment: `[A-Z][A-Z]+`? Or `[A-Z]{2,}`? What's an acronym for you? Is `S.H.I.E.L.D.`? Is `ToC`?

Comment: It's a good question. I decided it'll be a sequence of at least 2 capital letters. But, as you mentioned, it won't catch ToC.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as acronyms (I believe in your case) is capitals only. Then all you have to add is

`PATTERN = '[A-Z][A-Z]+'`

Which will check for at least 2 capitalized letters.

Answer (score 1):

The answer heavily depends on what do you consider an acronym, as m.buettner asked.

As a general suggestion, you may use `[A-Z]{2,}|([A-Z].){2,}[A-Z]?`, which will match things like the following:

```
AS | ASD | etc. (two or more)
A.S. | A.S.D. | etc. (two or more letters+period, ending with period)
A.S.D | A.S.D.F | etc. (two or more letters+period, ending without period)
```

**UPDATE:**

Another suggestion (given the "ToC" example) would be `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]`, which matches a string that starts and ends in uppercase: ToC, TOC, WOW, WoW, TOoTS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9+\.\&]*[A-Z0-9])\W` this should catch WoW W8 P&L, P+P etc. by allowing any combinations of lower case.

I would also strongly consider using [PyEnchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) as it would let you see if your suspected acronym is in the specified dictionary.